# Is it possible to access virtual methods of different ancestors of a polymorphic class through a single pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting, multiple-inheritance

I am building an interface, where it would be a little bit inconvenient to use separate variables to access individual interfaces, it would be great if somehow I could create a union of the two.

In a file:

```
struct A{
    virtual int auu() { return 41; }
};
struct B{
    virtual int boo() { return 43; }
};
```

In another file:

```
#include <path to A, B>
struct C : public A, public B{
    int auu() { return 20; }
    int boo() { return 22; }
};
```

And another file:

```
#include <declaration of A and B, but not C>

void doSth(A* a)
{
    B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
    /* I can only call auu with a */
    a->auu();
    /* I can only call boo with b */
    b->boo;

    /* Something like this would be ideal: */
    <??? type> * C_interface = dynamic_interface_cast<B*>(a)
    C_interface->auu();
    C_interface->boo();
}
```

So is there to call both auu and boo through only one pointer variable and without the knowledge of C's implementation (not casting it to )? Also I'd like to avoid creating inheritance hierarchy that is NOT in connection with class C.

Probably the answer is no, however I'm curious if an idea like this has come up from the side of the language developers because to my primitive mind it's not a so far fetched idea.

EDIT:
In real, A and B are abstract. A is a Simulation object that has methods like size() and length(). B is an IO interface, implementing getters and setters, but it doesn't know about sizes so I have to use both interfaces in many calculations. C is a specialized Simulation that implements the former 2.

EDIT:
I rewrote the question, maybe it actually makes sense now.

Comment: The design looks broken... what are you trying to achieve? The cast from B to A is logically incorrect.

Comment: A Tank is is a vehicle with a cannon. can a random cannon drive? can a random vehicle shoot?  this is what you're suggesting.

Comment: Logically incorrect? If I cast A to C and then C to B I'd get the same result as casting A to B, I suppose?

Comment: You are aware that the standard allows you to `dynamic_cast` from A to B if the pointer (or reference) is an instance of C?

Comment: if you use `static_cast` the compilation will fail, if you use `dynamic_cast` you will wither get a null pointer os an excetpion. if you use `reinterpret_cast` or C-style cast you will get undefined behaviour. I'll say it again - can a Subaro car shoot only because a tank is a vehicle and a cannon combined?

Comment: I second @Bathsheba. I think you want to create a C and cast it to whatever base class ptr/ref, or even better: call the functions right away.

Comment: What would be wrong with having one more class in the hierarchy to solve that problem?  X inherits from both A and B but doesn't override their methods, C inherits from X.  Your idea seems to depend on B having no data members.  If that is not correct, you need to think it through more.

Comment: @Andrew, yes you get the same result, because the pointer is really neither A nor B, but logically casting from A to B is incorrect because these classes are completely unrelated.

Comment: Not quite true, to repeat, you **can** `dynamic_cast` between A and B if your pointer  is an instance of a class that has A and B somewhere in its inheritance. That "somewhere" is arbitrary. I'm not claiming it's a good idea. I'm simply asserting that you can.

Comment: @Bathsheba of course. but not A* -> C* -> B*. it will fail for A* ->C* is A* is indeed an A object only, which is the idea that the OP suggests

Comment: @DavidHaim: absolutely.

Comment: Andrew, if I understand correctly you *do* have an object of type C (your specialized simulation). I guess you pass it to a function as an B*, but a B knows nothing about sizes etc. defined tin A. In that case yes, I think it is safe to dynamically cast from B* to A* when needed because a C is both, and a  cast "between siblings" is exactly one of the use cases for dynamic casts.

Comment: So I cannot get to a unrelated ancestor through a common derived class with an instance that is not in itself creating an is-a relationship between the the 2 ancestors.

Comment: @AndrewVegvari no, why would you do it when you have C to do exactly this?

Comment: You can (should) not "convert" an instance of class `A` that is not derived from `B` to an instance of `B` like in B * b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a); It will give you an `nullptr`.

Comment: Hgrmm.. Originally I wanted to write A * a = new C() ...not sure if I should correct it now..

Comment: So yeah, in light of the new info, namely that it was a typo and I wanted to create an instance of the derived (C), what could be the answer ? (just out of curiosity because I've already found another method). 

(I couldn't even have wanted to create an instance of A, because in my implementation A is abstract and has like 20 pure virtual methods :) )

I just lost my confidence with the little too negative first comment.

Answer (score 1):

I'll ilustrate the point I made in my comment. It's perfectly legal to cast between siblings, as long as the actual object is derived from both.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A{
    virtual int auu() { return 41; }
};
struct B{
    virtual int boo() { return 43; }
};

struct C : public A, public B{
    int auu() { return 20; }
    int boo() { return 22; }
};

void take_B(B* bp)
{
    cout << bp->boo() << endl; // expected
    cout << "(The base class would say " 
        << bp->B::boo() << ")" << endl; // base class implementation

    A *ap = dynamic_cast<A*>(bp);
    if(!ap) 
    {
        cerr << "weird, this cast should be possible!" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << ap->auu() << endl; // should work
        cout << "(The base class would say " 
            << ap->A::auu() << ")" << endl; // base class implementation
    }
}

int main()
{
   C c;
   take_B(&c);

   cout << endl << "... and again:" << endl;
   // just to clarify: The actual pointer type is irrelevant.
   B *bp = &c;
   take_B(bp);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I see, good demonstration. Although what I wanted to do could be achieved if A and B were to inherit a common, preferably empty class, right? (on the other hand it would create quite fragile code in the end I guess)

Comment: No, of course not! Just think about it -- if both D1 and D2 inherited from an empty B, their "specialties" would be unrelated. For example, a D1 object would not have data members defined in a D2 which D2's methods might access. If code for such D2 functions is executed on a D1 object it will access memory which just happens to be at that offset in a D2 but has no correspondence in a D1 (not to mention more complicated class layout issues). If you brute-force  call `((D2 *)d1p)->d2method()` you are calling it on the wrong object. A D1 *is not* a D2. (But both are Bs, of course.)

Comment: Yes, of course, I got it. Actually this is a topic that could be explained in seconds visually as opposed to thinking in pointers :))